# Error while using Entity Framework with Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, dll

I'm trying to create an API that will use my other project that uses Entity Framework 5.0.0. I added the other project as DLL and tried to create a controller that use one of the method in the other project but I'm getting this error:

> "{"Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"}"

The config file in the project that use the entity is using this version but the API using the latest one and when I'm trying to downgrade the version I'm getting error the it needs version above 6, and when trying to upgrade the version in the other project getting error about the provider.

I tried to change versions with no success, and search multiple sites solutions but nothing helped. When I am using the project without the API it works fine the problem occur only while trying to use it through the API Project.

Also tried to create controller that use entity framework but got the same error.

Comment: Upgrade the EF project. There are thorough descriptions available on the internet how to do that. If it doesn't succeed, edit your question and describe the details of what you did.

Comment: As I wrote when trying to update got an error about provider